# Bids Dataset Properties dialog has no datasource dropdownlist

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dialog, dataset, bids

I'm reading "SQL Server 2008 Report Services - Unleashed" and I'm reading the section on page 128 where they have the reader create a new dataset.

The photo in the book shows a slightly different Dataset Properties dialog window to the one I'm using. The one in the book shows a dropdown list for choosing a data source while the same dialog window I'm using does not. I looked at the other tabs on the left side of the window but did not find anything that would suggest the user can choose a data source for the dataset. The list of tabs on the left are also in a different order as well.

The photo in the book also shows a query text field in the window and mine does not.

There is text on the top area of the window says "Choose a data source and create a query" and a "Name" text field just like the book photo but after that everything is different. Mine has a radio button set ("Use a shared dataset" and "Use a dataset embedded in my report")

Clicking the OK button gives a message "<> Select a datasource". Could this be a Bids bug?

If I look at the same dialog when creating a report using the wizard it shows the same as in the book.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I hope this helps anyone who gets caught by this one. It had us guessing for hours.

Select the "Use a dataset embedded in my report" radio button and the dropdownlist will appear.